# How to modify a term reference autocomplete field

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms

I am using a term reference field but the widget type is autocomplete term widget. This term consist of many levels as parents and child. In the form I need to display only the child terms(only the lowest level in my case 3rd level) in this field. How can I do this. Please anyone help me on this. Thanks

Comment: Can you create your field via Views or it should be a CCK field?

Comment: Its not a field in views, it is a CCK field

Answer (score 1):

There's a GREAT module for this type of configurations called [Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select/)

> Hierarchical Select has the ability to save the entire lineage of a
>   selection or only the "deepest" selection. You can configure it to
>   force the user to make a selection as deep as possible in the tree, or
>   allow the user to select an item anywhere in the tree. Levels can be
>   labeled, you can configure limit the number of items that can be
>   selected, configure a title for the dropbox, choose a site-wide
>   animation delay, and so on. You can even create new items and levels
>   through Hierarchical Select!

This module has a lot to offer, but as for your need, it also does the trick.
Also you might want to consider [Taxonomy Term Reference Tree Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree) as well, the main functionality is a different thing but you can define a permission via views to do what you are after too with this module.

Comment: Thanks Sohail. But my field should be autocomplete not Hierarchical Select.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [Hierarchical Term Reference Autocomplete](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_ref_autocomplete) module could help you. It seems to combine the restriction of level of Hierarchical Select module (select only level 3 for you) and the Autocomplete widget.

Comment: Thanks. I tried with this module and configured the depth level as 3. But Auto-complete is not working. Is anything more to be done on this.

Comment: I tried on simplytestme and autocomplete worked fine: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0033gv4vc2

Comment: Thanks. This is not working for me, its may be because of any missing configuration. Can you please attach the settings you made on this field.

Comment: Nothing special, I just attached the Hierarchical Term Reference Autocomplete widget to the taxonomy field. It did the rest :-o

Could you please try on Simplytestme too to see if you still have the problem?

Comment: Yes it is working in Simplytestme. Don't know why it is not working in my project. But actually I need to display only the lowest levels. Here we can select values in all levels. I need to restrict this to 3rd level. Any idea on this? Thanks.

Comment: Can we implement this as  views exposed filer with autocomeplete?